# Add custom, multiple geom_vline to each faceted ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

I have a dataset where each species was mixed with a certain density (numeric) and type (numeric) of another species. I want to add two types of vertical lines to each of my facet_grid panels in ggplot: (a) A fixed line which dives the density/ type. e.g. 1000/1 = 1000, 1000/6 = 166.7, 10000/1 = 10000, 10000/6 = 1666.7

```
set.seed(111)
count <- rbinom(500,100,0.1) 
species <- rep(c("A","B"),time = 250)
density <- rep(c("1000","10000","1000","10000"),time = 125)
type <- rep(c("1","1","6","6"),time = 125)
df <- data.frame(species, density, type, count) # I feel too naiive, but I'm not able to get all the treatments filled. Gah.

ggplot(df, aes(x= count, colour = species, fill = species)) + 
   geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.5) + 
   theme_bw() + ylab("Frequency") + 
   facet_grid(species ~ type + density) + 
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
   theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(aspect.ratio = 1.75/1)
```

Comment: You have already post this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228622/how-to-custom-add-vertical-lines-to-ggplot-facet-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to custom add vertical lines to ggplot facet function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228622/how-to-custom-add-vertical-lines-to-ggplot-facet-function)

Comment: No, it doesn't. No one was able to answer the first part of the question.